# Tailwind workflow for same classes, but different HTML elements

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

For reusing styles in Tailwind have I found this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles

But I don't really know what the best worflow is for cases like this:

```
<x-heroicon-o-document-remove class="@if(request()->route()?->named('backoffice.cancellations.*')) text-gray-300 @else text-gray-400 @endif mr-4 h-6 w-6 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" />
```

```
<x-heroicon-o-truck class="@if(request()->route()?->named('backoffice.branch-movements.*')) text-gray-300 @else text-gray-400 @endif mr-4 h-6 w-6 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" />
```

I have 8 menu item icons with exactly the same style and I don't like to update the style on 8 places. I create normally a component, but the problem here is that there are different HTML elements.

I was thinking to layer components, but in the documantion stays:

> Whatever you do, don’t use @apply just to make things look “cleaner”.

I have tried to create a component, but I have different HTLML elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need solution specifically for Laravel you can create [dynamic component](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#dynamic-components)

Create `ui-icon.blade.php` under `resources/views/components`

*Do not use `icon` name as it reserved by [blade-icons package](https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons) (assuming you're using Heroicons subset of it)*

```html
@props(['name', 'isCurrent' => false])

<x-dynamic-component
    :component="'heroicon-o-'.$name"
    @class([
        'mr-4 h-6 w-6 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150', // common classes
        'text-gray-300' => $isCurrent, // classes applied for "current" route
        'text-gray-400' => ! $isCurrent, // classes applied for "non-current" route
    ])
/>
```

use it like

```html
<x-ui-icon name="document-remove" :is-current="request()->route()?->named('backoffice.cancellations.*')" />

// Always current
<x-ui-icon name="truck" :is-current="true" />

// Always NOT current as default prop for `isCurrent` set to false
<x-ui-icon name="clipboard" />
```

You may modify ui-icon component logic as you wish

About Tailwind recommendation to not use `@apply` - it is just recommendation. One of the points of using Tailwind is reusable utilities to prevent compiled CSS file to have same CSS properties over different selectors. Therefore if using `@apply` you may duplicate Tailwind-classes, compile it again in CSS-bundle and "kill" some point of using Tailwind  - you just writing CSS again but with a different syntax. I doubt if you add few lines of CSS with `@apply` it will harm your site performance...

```css
@layer components {
    .icon {
        @apply mr-4 h-6 w-6 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150;
    }
}
```

... but try to avoid it. Reusable components (in almost every front-end framework or template engine) is a way to solve this issue